# How do I set standard Interpreter path for python in vscode config json?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fish

I use fish shell and I just want to when I open the vscode it automatically selects the virtual environment that was activated in virtual fish.

I want to have something like this:

```json
"python.interpreterPath": "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/python"
```

(this variable actually doesn't exists, I just put it as an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P`: `Python: Select Interpreter`. It may suggest the correct path by itself, else you have to enter the path to the python executable you want to use by yourself.

Search in the fish documentation wether there is support for automatically passing the right interpreter path to VS-Code.

But that's the way how to do it manually at least.